# Redirect Links from + to -

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have just switched blogging platforms. All of the urls have stayed the same apart from the urls to the tags.

Previously if my blog had a tag 'Blue Widgets' the url would have been:
www.mysite.com/blog/tag/blue+widget/

The url on the new blog is:
www.mysite.com/blog/tag/blue-widget/

Is there any way I can auto redirect all of these. Maybe in .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule **as first rule** in your `/blog/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule "^(tag)/([^+]*)\++([^+]*\+.*)$" /$1/$2-$3 [N]
RewriteRule "^(tag)/([^+]*)\+([^+]*)$" /$1/$2-$3 [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add it to the .htaccess.  I am using the FishPig Wordpress/Magento integration so this .htaccess file is ignored.  Is there similar code I can run from the base .htaccess?

Comment: Yes this rule should work from base taxes also just make it (/?tag) at the start with a leading slash.